# Retrieve filename in a variable

Tags: php

To move file from folder to another I use this code:

```
$new_file = new File($file['destination']->getPath() . File::SEPARATOR . $file['file']->getName());
```

Now, I need to add a unique ID and store a filename in database.
OK for uniqid():

```
$new_file = new File($file['destination']->getPath() . File::SEPARATOR . uniqid() . '---' . $file['file']->getName());
```

Result in a filename like this:
514685b08e6db---SL004321_7_03-2013.pdf

Now, how to retrieve filename in a variable to store this on MySQL?

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking here, can you clarify what your problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you coud store it in a variable and use, like

```
$filename = uniqid() . '---' . $file['file']->getName(); //your filename
$new_file = new File($file['destination']->getPath() . File::SEPARATOR . $filename);
```